# Problem with MongoDB connection of server

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, permissions

I've a problem with my configuration on mongodb.
My configuration is:

- **Linux Ubunut 18.04LTS**

I've follow documentation MongoDB.org. Every going well.
But I meetting problem when I run mongod command.
He return me that:

```
2020-07-07T12:59:43.510+0200 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
2020-07-07T12:59:43.510+0200 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2020-07-07T12:59:43.510+0200 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I tested of remove /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock and of change  administratif law:

```
# rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock 
# sudo systemctl start mongod
# sudo mongod
# ls -la /tmp/
```

Return :

```
srwx------  1 usr usr     0 juil.  7 13:14 mongodb-27017.sock
```

```
# sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock 
# ls -la /tmp/
# srwx------  1 mongodb mongodb     0 juil.  7 13:14 mongodb-27017.sock
```

If I raise mongod command:

```
2020-07-07T13:19:43.641+0200 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-07-07T13:19:43.644+0200 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-07-07T13:19:43.644+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23119 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=dasco-UX32VD
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.8
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2020-07-07T13:19:43.645+0200 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Finally, if I do:

```
# mongod --port 27018
```

Return

```
2020-07-07T13:24:57.906+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2020-07-07T13:24:57.906+0200 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-07-07T13:24:57.906+0200 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-07-07T13:24:57.906+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-07-07T13:24:57.906+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

But /data/ it's ok

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb mongodb 4096 juil.  6 20:23 /data/db
```

And if I run sudo mongod , it doesn't work:

```
# sudo mongod

....
2020-07-07T13:27:51.499+0200 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2020-07-07T13:27:51.499+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-07-07T13:27:51.499+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48

# ls -la /tmp/
srwx------  1 root  root      0 juil.  7 13:27 mongodb-27017.sock
```

That change law

For finish if I do:

```
# sudo mongod --port 27018
```

I don't have a problem...
You have solution please?

Comment: What is the `usr` user?

Comment: You are also not following the instructions exactly as they are written.

Comment: user it's my name, I've just change for the post.
Why you say me that I have not follow instructions?

Comment: You are running `mongod` with different users. That is not part of instructions.

Comment: no I just testing with sudo because without sudo it does not work. And when I changed users with chown command, I just following instruction on stackoverflow. Therefore I don't understant when you say me that

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I've following all documentation, and I've always error. Why you don't check my request? I don't understand, I know that I 've me of deceive somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: You are running mongod as different users, which can be done but requires understanding of what happens in that case. I suggest you follow the tutorial as written and if you are having difficulty start from the beginning.